# how to get the total sum (specifically)

Tags: mysql

Fe_Order_Items

```
fe_order_items_id
fe_order_specification_id
fe_users_id
fe_menu_items_id
fe_order_items_quantity
fe_order_items_time_order
```

Fe_Order_Specification

```
fe_order_specification_id
fe_users_id
fe_users_address_id
fe_users_email_address_id
fe_users_phone_number_id
fe_menu_items_id
fe_menu_items_quantity
fe_payment_customer_payment_order_total
fe_payment_customer_payment_acceptance
fe_payment_customer_payment_acceptance_by_food_express
fe_payment_customer_method_of_payment
fe_customer_service_order_process_start
fe_delivery_system_order_signed_by_customer_before_delivery
fe_delivery_system_order_order_delivered_to_customer
total
```

The query I ran (my mentor helped me with it, because it is still too difficult to come up with something to calculate the total (of all the inserted menu items that have been ordered):

```
SELECT fe_order_specification.fe_order_specification_id, 
    fe_menu_items.fe_menu_items_name, 
    SUM(fe_menu_items.price `fe_menu_items_quantity`) AS Total 
FROM fe_order_items
INNER JOIN fe_menu_items          ON fe_order_items.fe_menu_items = fe_menu_items.fe_menu_items_id
INNER JOIN fe_order_specification ON fe_order_items.`fe_order_specification` = fe_order_specification.`fe_order_specification_id`
WHERE fe_order_items.fe_order_specification=1
GROUP BY fe_order_items.fe_menu_items
```

Instead of getting a nice total sum, mysql gave me something in french (and english ((my settings are on English UK, everything is in English)):

> 1054 - Champ 'fe_order_specification.fe_order_specification_id' inconnu dans field list

Comment: How do you know what is a dinner and what is a dessert. Sample data would help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so i edited my text and added another table

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the query to look as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(mi.price * oi.quantity)
FROM order_items AS oi
JOIN menu_items AS mi ON mi.id = oi.menu_item_id
WHERE oi.order_id = @ORDERID
```

However, I'm afraid this does not match you current datamodel... I would change...

- order item to be in a has many relationship with order
- each order item to have one menu item, not relate to many.  This is the key area that makes a query very hard with the tables you have presented, but easier if you change to order item has one menu item

And the datamodel would look like this (note I have removed fields not important to the query):

order_items:

```
id (PK) (AUTO INCREMENTED) (INT)
order_id (FK) (INT)
menu_item_id (FK) (INT)
quantity (INT)
```

menu_items:

```
id (PK) (AUTO INCREMENTED) (INT)
price (DECIMAL)
```

Other notes:

- I would store the `user_id` on the `order` table (which has not been defined yet)
- I would store the type of menu item on the menu item: `type (ENUM) ['dinner','dessert']`
- If it is needed to control the number of these items that should be done programmatically

Comment: @LayilahBrown but of course think it over, if it helps I've written/maintained over a hundred booking systems so I'm very sure this is the route to go.  If this is of benefit please upvote/accept :)

Comment: Hi @LayilahBrown you would be best updating the content of the question before I looked again, however it is very likely that my answer will remain unchanged due to my experience.

Comment: I am still unchanged in my view/answer - however as the answer is unacceptable - I've re formatted your question (again) in the hope someone else will help you.